# Is it possible have all 3rd party emojis to look same size?

Tags: css, emoji, twemoji

Is it possible to have external emojis to look the same size? We are currently using twemojis in a NextJS app, here is what they look like:

[image: twemojis on same line]

The pineapple looks smaller than the smartphone, as if we "forced" the underlying SVG to be 32px*32px

Any idea?